# Subset does not seem to work

Tags: r

I have a dataset called "ikr_data".

The `colnames` look this:

```
colnames(ikr_data)
#[1] "Count"           "VRTG_ID_NR"      "EEG_VRTG_CAT_V"  "GEBR_IDENT_KEUR" "PL_KEURING"      "NAAM_VRTG_AANB"  "DAT_RESULT_KEUR"
#[8] "TYD_RESULT_KEUR" "KL_CODE_EU_1"    "KL_CODE_EU_2"    "RES_CODE_KEUR"   "KENT_LAND_OORS"  "LAND_HERK"       "YEAR"
```

I now want to make a subset of all the data from the years > 2009. But if I do

```
ikr_data_relevant_years <- ikr_data[ikr_data$YEAR >=2009, ]
Warning message:
  In Ops.factor(ikr_data$YEAR, 2009) : ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors
```

It doesn't work. Strange because this does work:

```
x <- ikr_data[ikr_data$YEAR => 2009, ]
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: `=>` is not valid syntax. Anyway, `ikr_data$YEAR` is a factor. Find out why it is not numeric and fix that. Possibly, there are non-numeric entries in the data you imported to R.

Comment: If you're happy to discard any non-numeric years, you could do `ikr_data$YEAR <- as.numeric(as.character(ikr_data$YEAR))`.

Comment: Thanks @Roland. It turned out ikr_data$YEAR was a factor. I made it numeric now doing: ikr_data$YEAR <- as.numeric(ikr_data$YEAR). But now I get the following error: Error: unexpected '=' in "x <- ikr_data[ikr_data$YEAR ="

Comment: Did you try `x <- ikr_data[ikr_data$YEAR >= 2009, ]`?